# How to make a hyperlink navigate to the top of the figure in LaTeX when using hyperref?

Tags: latex, viewport, captions, figures

I have a LaTeX document with a figure and references to it:

```
\begin{figure}
...
\caption{...}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:1}
```

I use the hyperref package to get hyperlinks in the resulting PDF.
However the link to the figure navigates to the caption leaving the figure itself out of the view. How can I make it navigate to the start of the figure instead without moving the caption to the top?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To previous comment:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
```

is slightly better than `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` because when you use e.g. `figure` without captions there won't be a compilation problem. The caption package by default sets option

```
hypcap=true
```

anchoring hyperlinks to the beginning of an environment.

Comment: If for some reason you can't use the caption package, you can prevent hypcap compilation errors for figures without a caption with `\capstartfalse` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240261/88028

Comment: For some reason, the caption package changes the font size of figure captions.

Answer (score 37):

Add this in your preamble

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    %for going to the top of an image when a figure reference is clicked
```

Make sure that the `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}` is written after the hyperref package is imported.

Answer (score -1):

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Using this is a better idea than `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate why it is better?