# Is it possible to get LaTeX to link to the top of a figure rather than to its caption?

Tags: label, latex, figure, caption

In my TeX file I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=5in]{screens/main.png}
        \caption{\label{fig:MainScreen} Screenshot of the main screen of TADA.}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I reference the figure earlier on in my document:

```
...in Figure \ref{fig:MainScreen}.
```

...if I click on the reference in Preview (Mac) it takes me to where the `\label` command is (which is below the actual image in the figure).  That is, the document is scrolled to where the caption is at the top of the page, which is somewhat annoying if I'm trying to look at the figure itself.

My question to you is, can I get LaTeX to create a reference to the **top** of the figure while keeping the `\caption` command at the bottom?  For stylistic purposes I must keep the caption below the figure.

My only thought was to move the `\label` command to before the `\includegraphics` command, but apparently `\caption` has to come before `\label` for the referencing to work correctly.

Comment: just a quick somewhat unrelated comment; I believe it's generally preferable to use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment as it tends to add bit of extra vertical space that can be unwanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a hyperlink navigate to the top of the figure in LaTeX when using hyperref?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023925/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-navigate-to-the-top-of-the-figure-in-latex-when-using-hy)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have a look at the hypcap package documentation (CTAN is your friend: https://ctan.org/), but as a quick summary you should be able to simply put

`\usepackage[all]{hypcap}`

somewhere after you load hyperref and it will just work.