# minipage and ref

Tags: latex

I have got a multicolumn environment where I put figures into a minipage since the figure environment seems to be incompatible with multicols (at least that is what I read and indeed, putting a \begin{figure} into \begin{multicols} environment makes the illustration disappear.

Now the problem I am facing with the code below is, that, if I click on the \ref link on the bottom, the pdf reader jumps to the caption instead of the minipage resulting in the figure itself not being visible:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to make sure, \ref jumps to the top of the minipage environment rather than the top of the \captionof?

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{sketch}
        \vspace*{-7mm}
        \captionof{figure}{Iconic Pencil Figure~\cite{mobi_pencil_figure}}
        \label{fig:background--iconic-pencil-figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{multicols}

Figure~\ref{fig:background--iconic-pencil-figure}}
```

Comment: Please make a *compilable* [mre], not just a code fragment.

Comment: See [Is it possible to get LaTeX to link to the top of a figure rather than to its caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6695212/12122460) for ways to link to the top of the figure.