# Make a link that centers an equation latex

Tags: latex

I have this example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\section{Introduction1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1} 
a = b + c +d \cdot a
\end{equation}
\newpage
\section{Introduction2}
\newpage
\section{Introduction3}
\eqref{eq:1}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

this link works but when I press it the equation appears at the very top of the screen I would prefer the equation to be in the center after pressing the link, is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is a latex problem, but rather of the pdf viewer. Consequently, this question might be better suited for superuser unless you plan to program your own pdf viewer ...

Comment: well I think it is latex as their is also a way to jump to above a figure for example using hypcap or caption package (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023925/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-navigate-to-the-top-of-the-figure-in-latex-when-using-hy) these dont work for this case but is assume where a link jumps too is not pdf viewer specific? @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Jumping above the figure is done by placing the hyperlink anchor at this position. Your pdf viewer will still put the anchor at the top of the screen. In theory you could tell latex latex to shift the anchor and place it somewhere above the equation, but how can it know how big your screen is, which zoom level you use etc.? That's a job for the pdf viewer.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz does this mean this is just not possible? as I dont have any control over what pdf viewer other people use to view my documents.

Comment: If you intend for other people to use your document, that's even worse. People are used to see the link anchor at the top of the screen and will be confused if they don't get the equation there but half a page away.

Comment: well I guess its just me then it just looked wierd that when I pressed my link it jumped to section 3 fully in my screen and at the very very top it just showed my equation (not the example code but actual thing I was doing) @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz